# How can I compare two columns then return the value from third or fourth?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To make things easier I will explain what my document contains: I have 3 sheets in excel. The first and second contain Product Numbers and product Labels. The third sheet combines both sheets' product numbers, I want to compare both sheets product numbers and find the corresponding product label.

Which function would I use to do this? I would want the formula to search column 2 for any matching product numbers from column 1 and fetch the product label which matches. If not, I would want it to search column 3 and fetch the right product label from that sheet.

Sheet called "FORM" which needs labels from other 2 which match part number

[image: Sheet which needs part label]

Sheet called "B2B"

[image: One of the sheets which contains labels]

Sheet called "B2C"

[[image: Second sheet which contains labels[3]

Comment: You shoul use IF statement with link to other sheet in excell

Comment: I have used =if(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!A2=Sheet3!A2,Sheet3!B2) but this doesn't work? @KlapenHz

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your spreadsheet and example desired results.

Comment: Screenshots now added - @ImaginaryHuman072889

Comment: I think you are missing an image of a sheet as there is no column 3 containing a label. The actual sheet names are needed as well.

Comment: Now added, thanks - @QHarr

Comment: Are you trying to use the partnumber in the Form sheet to retrieve the partname from sheet B2B and if not found in B2B try B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E2 of Form sheet paste

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B2B!A:E,5,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,B2C!A:E,5,FALSE)),"Not found")
```

Then drag this formula down for however many rows you are trying to retrieve partnames for.